# Phonegap: Scroll top on statusbar tap

Tags: ios, cordova, scroll, statusbar

I am implementing a webapp using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. One thing I am missing, is the following: The App should scroll to the top when the statusbar is tapped.

I have already seen that using Objective C one has to indicate the view that has to scroll to top on tap. Is it possible to do something similar with Javascript/Phonegap?

Comment: The status bar is not part of the App. Phonegap can't register any clicks on it. Without writing your own plugin anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was clear to me. But I am unsure if it is possible over all to write such a plugin, since I would have to indicate in that plugin which view to scroll. And all my views are not Objective C types, but html.

Comment: You're right, I don't think it is possible :(

Answer (score 8):

**Update for 22.9.2016**

### It's working fine

Plugin ID has changed, install it using:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Tested with cordova-6.3.1 cordova-ios-4.2.2 in the iOS 10.0 simulator and an iPhone 6s Plus running 9.3.5.

---

The official status-bar plugin has this feature.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Install:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

In your javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('statusTap', function() {
    //scroll-up or do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I can't see it in the docs for this plugin.

Comment: Yep, it's working great. It's not in the docs, I found it in the code: (line 102) https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/www/statusbar.js

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a plugin to solve this issue

https://github.com/j-mcnally/cordova-statusTap

you can register tap events on the status bar and handle this all in code. With an event listener.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this. I can't wait to try it out!

Comment: I've been looking for exactly that too. Is there something like this registered as an adobe phonegap build plugin.

Comment: App just crashes while starting if I add this. I have added plugin as described here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/722

Answer (score 0):

if the content that you are displaying in the phonegap app is bigger then the bounds of the webview, the scroll happens automatically.

Otherwise - for example if you are just scrolling a div using -webkit-overflow-scrolling - you need to use the solution found here:
[How to detect touches in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar)

In the scrollViewShouldScrollToTop you need to call

```
[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"should_scroll_to_top"];
```

should_scroll_to_top is a normal function in your js.

Comment: Yes, I am using fixed toolbars within PhoneGap. Thus the content of my webview is not bigger than the webview itself.

Since I am not really familiar with Obj C I only understand parts of this, but it sounds as if it could be a solution. Am I right that in theory I would have to do the things as decribed: Explicitly create a hidden ScrollView in PhoneGap and apply the other stuff mentioned there.

But: At the end of this solution is said, that it only works if there is no other view that reacts to these events. And as far as I understand, the webview is reacting to it. Does it still work?

Comment: i am using this solution in one of my apps. since my content is, like yours, not bigger then the webview, i have disabled the webview from receiving the events. and it works. my js function checks which page is current and hnows which divs it has that are scrollable.