# Detect tap on iOS status bar with Trigger.io

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I want to implement "tap on status bar to scroll to top" for my Trigger.io app that is using custom scrolling. Is there any way (e.g. an event) to detect this tap ot is a similiar feature planned for the future?

[image: iPod status bar]

Comment: I think if you are using `UITableView` then that is default functionality. You mentioned you are using custom scrolling, does that mean you are not using `UITableView`?

Comment: I'm using a `UIWebview` through Trigger.io with [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for custom scrolling.

Comment: Please have look at [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html) blog post. I believe you will get your answer. Don't forget to rate the answer if you like it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I cannot run any native code within the UIWebView, but the blog post is definitely something for the Trigger developers (in case they want to implement an event for this) @james-brady

Comment: You can get status bar tap notification. Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar/16787113#16787113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the trigger.io [api docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/index.html) - **no**.  Hopefully someday we'll be able to write plug-ins.

Comment: As Kris said, not supported now: I'll put an item in our backlog, although I think it might well be the sort of thing supported via plugins before we get to it as a core feature!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to mimic this cordova's plugin:
https://github.com/welldone-software/cordova-statusTap