# UIScrollView scroll to the bottom when status bar touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out how to scroll to the bottom of a UIScrollView when the status bar is touched. I'm familiar with the @property(nonatomic) BOOL scrollsToTop method in UIScrollView, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I also have this method here that automatically scrolls to the bottom when the view loads. Any thoughts?

```
-(void)scrollToBottom{
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scroller.contentSize.height - scroller.bounds.size.height);
[scroller setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [How to detect touches in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar). Here it is suggested to use a transparent UIView over the status bar and detect touches.