# How to handle statusBar press event on IOS?

Tags: ios, statusbar

To cause  my tableView to scroll up  when i'm pressing  the status bar, 
I'm defining my table view as:

```
myTableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

and other views as:

```
otherTableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

The thing is i have screens that involve many scrollable views and this solution won't work for this specific screens.....
in addition i want to make some views to disappear when pressing on the status bar, 
and i wonder if there's a way to handle this kind of events?

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar may help you

Comment: thanx , it works perfectly well on an empty project but in my company project it won't react when i'm pressing on the status bar, strange... i even tried to put a gesture recognizer on the it but it won't work on the status bar area

Comment: solved it...found a line in my code that defines the uiwindow differently.... 1000 thanks!