# Status bar tap should scroll table view to the top

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anybody please tell me how to implement tap on status bar and table view should scroll to top. I also have another scroll view in that view controller for some different purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This i done automatically is it not?

Comment: @SundeepSaluja Can I know how you solved this because I am also stuck on this .

Comment: @Pavan More This faeture will not work if you have more than one control in your class dxerived from UIScrollView.

Comment: @Pavan More This feature will not work by default if you have more then one control derived from UIScrollView in your class. So I wrote custom code for this. By adding a view on window with frame exactly same as that of status bar. And on tap of that view i did my work. I can provide the code if you need??

Answer (score 15):

If you are having more than one scrollview inside the viewcontroller, you set setScrollsToTop property to YES for the scrollview you want to scroll when user taps status bar. And also set that property to NO for all other scrollviews.
If there is only one scrollview/tableview, You don't even need to do this. It will be set automatically.

**[myScrollView setScrollsToTop:YES];**

**[otherScrollview setScrollsToTop:NO];**

Comment: Did that,, But was not working for me. Finally got a hack from here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar

Comment: I encountered this issue when using a slide navigation framework. The menu that appeared from the left (after pressing the hamburger icon) contained a list of menu items in a scroll view. So I had to `setScrollsToTop:NO` on this scroll view for all the sub-views to work correctly!