# How to detect the status bar is tapped?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios7, ios6

In iOS7 & iPad. When I tap on the status bar, I need to call the method which will perform some actions. So can anyone provide me the right solution?

Comment: you can use tap gesture recognizers to do it.

Comment: try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar