# How to make pressing the status bar scroll to the top of any UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView within my UIViewController.

I want the table to scroll to the top when the status bar is pressed. i've tried `self.tableView.scrollsToTop = YES` but it does not scroll the table to the top.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Your responders are not linking up. Using `UITableViewController` will do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for UIScrollView, scrolls to top, there is a special consideration: "on iPhone, the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more than one scroll view on-screen that has scrollsToTop set to yes."

This *could* be part of the issue, without seeing your actual code.

Another technique you might employ since it sounds like a uitableview nested inside a view controller, is to call scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

So, detect when status bar is pressed, then call [YourTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:probably0 atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES/NO];

Comment: thanks for your answer, would scrollViewShouldScrollToTop detect when a status bar is pressed?

Comment: Here are some approaches to the problem of knowing when a user taps the status bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar