# In Swift, how can I detect a tap on the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift

My status bar will never be hidden throughout my entire app. Is there a simple way to detect it when it is tapped?

Comment: I don't think you can get touch events for touching the status bar, but i might be mis-understanding you. You want to get touch events for touching the 20 pixel height bar at the very top of the screen?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the tap event for that.

Comment: Off the top of my head with no research, you can add a button on top of the window that might receive the touches for that area....

Comment: I want to use the status bar because it's always on top of every view controller

Comment: @A'saDickens what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar

Comment: That creates a touchable square for your entire screen that happens to be in the same place as the status bar, which works for what you want. Sounds good :3