# Can we monitor the statusBar click event?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any **notification** when user clicked the statusBar?I want to do something specifically when user click the statusBar so I need to know the event occur time.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect touches in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.By the way this is tapped solution.not clicked solution.because status bar is not button like element.:)

Here is swift 3 version:

in Appdelegate function add this line.

```
let statusBarTappedNotification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "statusBarTappedNotification"))
```

then add this function.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let statusBarRect = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    guard let touchPoint = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.window) else { return }

    if statusBarRect.contains(touchPoint) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(statusBarTappedNotification)
    }
}
```

Now it's ready for cooking.:) in your view controller where you are using.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: statusBarTappedNotification.name, object: .none, queue: .none) { _ in
    print("Viola, i have been tapped!!!!")
}
```