# Handle StatusBar tap/onPress in iOS (React Native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, statusbar

Is there any way i can control the tap or onPress of StatusBar in iOS? By clicking on centre of the status bar scrolls the list to top. I would like to override this and provide my own logic.
is it possible?

I have tried adding listener to listen for the onPress change using `addListener` but no such function. I have also tried wrapping `StatusBar` with `TouchableOpacity`, still it does not work.

Comment: Can you provide me a code snippets? Setting top to 0 does not work still

Comment: Please check it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar

Comment: I'm looking for a React-Native solution. I don't have knowledge on iOS to use that logic as NativeModule.

Answer (score 1):

React Native core gives you the option with `onScrollToTop` function
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscrolltotop-ios