# The tap gesture isn't detected on the status bar area?

Tags: ios, notifications, uigesturerecognizer, statusbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

The title explains it all.

Is there any way to detect a tap gesture on the status bar in iOS 11?

I've already googled for this, and tried as suggested, but they all seem to be outdated answers somehow.

I wonder if there's anyone who has already figured out how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let statusBarRect = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    guard let touchPoint = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.window) else { return }

    if statusBarRect.contains(touchPoint) {
      // tap on statusbar, do something
    }
}
```

Note, this no longer works on iOS 13 and newer.
For iOS 13 and newer use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897714/1351469

Comment: Are you sure that this code works? The touchBegan function is not called for the status bar rect from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, working fine on my iPhone X with iOS 11.2.6, when touching the status bar or the notch.

Comment: You are right. I tried implementing it in the very AppDelegate other than other views, it is detected. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with iOS 16.

Comment: For iOS 13 and newer use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897714/1351469