# iOS13: how to detect a status bar click event?

Tags: objective-c, ios13

In my appDelegate, I override `touchesBegan` to detect when the status bar is clicked:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint location = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:kWindow];
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(statusBarFrame, location)) {
        ///do something 
    }
}
```

Before iOS 13, this worked; on iOS 13, it does not. The method is never executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can get help from this article - https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

Comment: Or you can fix this issue by following the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar/3753976

Comment: @dfwang Did you get any solution for the same?

Comment: Anyone got solution ??

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I found that the status bar is no longer part of the application on iOS13, it’s part of the system UI (“springboard”). You need to access it via [UIStatusBarManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarmanager)

So this no longer works:

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
```

In iOS 13, you need to get the StatusBar frame like this:

```
UIStatusBarManager *manager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager;
CGRect statusBarFrame = manager.statusBarFrame;
```

Comment: hi, alxlives, Thank you for your answer. I tried to use UIStatusBarManager create a view, and add the tap event to this view, but is not responding.

Comment: Hello. I don’t really understood the create a view part. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953439/3241041) but getting the statusbar frame from UIStatusBarManager ?

Comment: @alxlives I think what @dfwang is doing is using the UIStatusBarManager's frame to create a view in the same position, then use that view to intercept touch events? I'm not sure that would work though. The link you posted relies on `touchesBegan` being called but that doesn't get called when the status bar is tapped in iOS 13.
So far, I'm not seeing a way to detect taps on the status bar in iOS 13 yet.

Comment: @Xeaza Did you find any solution to detect touch on status bar?

Comment: @JayeshkumarSojitra, not yet. I have this open question which includes what I've found out so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806710/touchesbegan-is-called-in-ios-12-but-is-not-called-in-ios-13

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13, StatusBar Event was managed by `UIStatusBarManager`, these methods will be called when click the StatusBar:

```
-[UIStatusBarManager _handleScrollToTopAtXPosition:]
-[UIStatusBarManager handleTapAction:]
```

So, you can hook `-[UIStatusBarManager handleTapAction:]` to detecte StatusBar click event

Comment: `_handleScrollToTopAtXPosition` is private so I don't think I can listen to it, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into the problem of animating a view if the user clicks on the *status bar* or on the empty *dynamic island* for quickly scrolling the page to top, then I suggest you using `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool` method.

Here's the method:

```
func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
    // Animation code here
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask for upvotes. It is against SO policy and it's just noise in your question.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-should-we-do-with-users-who-ask-for-upvotes-and-to-accept-their-answers and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271810/is-it-ok-to-ask-to-upvote-accept-my-own-answers among several others you can find on the subject.