# How to detect status bar taps in iOS13?

Tags: swift, status, ios13

I used the code below before, and it worked perfectly fine in iOS12:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let statusBarRect = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame

        guard let touchPoint = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.window) else { return }

        if statusBarRect.contains(touchPoint) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(statusBarTappedNotification)
        }
}
```

But it does not work in iOS13 anymore. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, looks like that the only working way in iOS13 I have found so far in to add a dummy UIScrollView... Not the most elegant solution, but it works at least: 

    self.dummyScrollview.frame = self.view.frame
        self.dummyScrollview.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.height + 1
        self.dummyScrollview.contentOffset.y = 1

        dummyScrollview.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(dummyScrollview)

    func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO ON STATUS BAR TAP HERE
        return false
    }

Comment: Here is a solution which is still works in iOS 13:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753976/9087914

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to detect the tap with an Objective-C category of `UIStatusBarManager`. I don't think it's possible as a swift extension or other swift way.

```
@implementation UIStatusBarManager (CAPHandleTapAction)
-(void)handleTapAction:(id)arg1 {
    // Your code here
}
@end
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution but it seems to disable the scroll-to-top behaviour, is there a way to get that back while also using this?

Comment: yeah, but it involves swizzling https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/7cb77c87333fb88a2b9d4eefb784d84fe2083c9c/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/UIStatusBarManager%2BCAPHandleTapAction.m